Removing false wall and attaching wall frame to brick
I am looking to remove a false wall that was built over a brick chimney to house the breaker panel. However, the false wall abuts a bathroom wall and the framing. Because of the false wall, the bathroom gains about 4” of width because the wall is offset from the chimney.
If I move the circuit panel and remove the false wall, do I then have to join the bathroom wall framing to the exposed brick directly? Or can one side of the framing be offset somehow from the chimney? I know it will look funny with the outside of the bathroom wall not flush to the brick, but the drywall inside the bathroom can be at least close to brick and I won’t lose the space from moving the wall framing.

Some pictures and / or diagrams would greatly enhance your query.
